# How do I make NetBeans search for my files in the src folder instead of the dist folder?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, path, src

I'm using `JavaFX` to create an application. Every time time I try to run it, I get a `LoadException`. The problem is that when I try to run this code, for example:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainTabPane.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    stage.setTitle("Global Car Trading");
}
```

It searches for the MainTabPane.fxml using this path:

> file:/C:/Users/Jesper/Documents/NetBeansProjects/3semester/trunk/dist/GlobalCarTrading.jar!/GUI/MainTabPane.fxml

But the file is not located in the dist folder, it's located in the `src` folder. How do I fix this?

Location of fxml and class files: 
C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\NetBeansProjects\3semester\trunk\src\GUI

When the code is

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI/MainTabPane.fxml"));:
```

I get the following exceptions:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at         sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/1268447657.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3201)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
at GUI.GlobalCarTrading.start(GlobalCarTrading.java:23)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1715882599.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1127003017.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1108411398.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1147985808.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Exception running application GUI.GlobalCarTrading
```

When I remove the "GUI/" part, like this:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainTabPane.fxml"));:
```

I also get this exception:

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:   file:/C:/Users/Jesper/Documents/NetBeansProjects/3semester/trunk/dist/GlobalCarTrading.jar!/GUI/MainTabPane.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
at GUI.GlobalCarTrading.start(GlobalCarTrading.java:23)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/281867444.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/170597113.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1108411398.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1147985808.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Comment: Can you add the location of class and fxml files in your project?

Comment: You don't want it to look in the src folder: there is no guarantee the src folder will even exist when the application runs.

Comment: @James_D In fact it's highly likely that it won't.

Comment: Can you post the .fxml file? Also what project type are you using? There is a specific project type for use with fxml (Category = JavaFX, Type = JavaFX FXML Application) that might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

It is not looking for the file in the dist folder it is looking for the resource in the Jar in the dist folder. Jar files are actually zip files and can have files and directories within them. This is the correct place for it to look since when you distribute the application the user will need access to the .fxml file and not have your source. Files in you source directory are stored in the jar file when the jar is built.  You can make this code work by placing the MainTabPane.fxml in the same directory as this class which appears to be the src/GUI directory. Another option would be to use:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getSystemResource("MainTabPane.fxml"));
```

This will also get MainTabPane.fxml from the jar file in the dist folder, but it will get it from the top-level directory within the jar file where files from the src directory are stored instead of the GUI subdirectory within the jar.

Comment: Do you mean that i should place MainTabPane.fxml in the same folder as the .jar file? The path for the .jar file is C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\NetBeansProjects\3semester\trunk\dist\GlobalCarTrading.jar

Comment: No I mean put it in the same directory as the .java file that calls getClass(). It will be copied from this directory into the jar file in the same corresponding subdirectory when the jar is built.

Comment: Can you unzip the jar file and post a listing of the files in the jar file, and a listing of the files in the src directory being careful to show the folder structure?

Comment: It is possible you just need to rebuild to get things in sync.

Comment: I just checked and the files in the src folder and .jar file are exactly the same, except there's a folder called META-INF in the .jar file with the file "MANIFEST.MF" inside.

Comment: The META-INF directory just has some extra information about the jar that is probably not relevant for this problem. Maybe there is  another issue. Can you post the full text of the Exception?

Answer (score 0):

getClass() gets the class from which it is called. If the resource is in the same folder/package you can directly get it with getResource("file"). If the file is in a parent folder/package or in a different folder/package you can call getClass().getResource("../foo/file"). This might not be the best solution but it works.

Comment: For what reason? Any exception? You can get content by adding .getContent() which will give you a BufferedInputStream. Read chars to string and them parse.

Comment: I'm getting these: InvocationTargetException, RuntimeException, NullPointerException

Comment: It may be reading the .fxml just fine but the .fxml file has something wrong with it.   Open up the .fxml file and try Source-> Make Controller.

Comment: Try this:
`BufferedInputStream input = (BufferedInputStream) getClass().getResource("../foo/file.ext").getContent();
    String content = "";
    while (input.available() > 0) {
        content += (char) input.read();
    }`

Comment: @Jesper, perhaps this: `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainTabPane.fxml").getContent());`